# Como imprimir conteudo de um template gerado dinamicamente com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

Galera, criei um sisteminha de pedidos online para hamburgueria, uma landpage com o cardapio e opção de enviar o pedido pelo whatsapp. Ocorre que eu gostaria tambem de imprimir cada pedido feito.
Para mandar o pedido pelo whatsapp eu criei um metodo que percorre o carrinho de compras e cria um template conforme os itens do pedido, jogo tudo numa variavel, depois transformo numa url.
Ja tentei de tantas as formas mandar mesmo conteudo para uma mini impressora termica, usando o window.print. Tive a ideia de abrir uma pagina em branco e jogar o conteudo da variavel texto, mas ficou tudo meios desajustado, junto, numa linha só.
vejam meu metodo:

```
finalizarPedido: () => {
           if (meu_Carrinho.length >0 && meu_Endereco != null) {

                var texto = 'Olá, eu gostaria de fazer um pedido,';
                texto += `\n*Itens do Pedido:*\n\n\${itens}`; 
                texto += '\n*Endereço de Entrega:*'; 
                texto += `\n${meu_Endereco.endereco}, ${meu_Endereco.numero}, ${meu_Endereco.bairro}`; 
                texto += `\n${meu_Endereco.cidade} - ${meu_Endereco.Uf} / ${meu_Endereco.cep} ${meu_Endereco.complemento}`; 
                texto += `\n\n*Total (com entrega): R$ ${(valor_Carrinho + valor_Entrega).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',')}*`; 

                var itens = '';

                $.each(meu_Carrinho, (i, e ) => {

                    itens += `*${e.quantidade}x* ${e.name}........R$ ${e.price.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',')} \n`; 
                    
                    // verificando se o each chegou ao ultimo item

                    if ((i + 1) == meu_Carrinho.length) {

                        texto = texto.replace(/\${itens}/g, itens);

                 //     encodificando a variavel texto para URL do whatsapp

                     let encode = encodeURI(texto);

                   //  criando a URL 

                   //   let URL = `https://wa.me/5598970220128?text=${encode}`;

                      let URL = `https://wa.me/${celular_Empresa}?text=${encode}`;

                    //  atrubuindo o endereço URL ao href do Botao Enviar Pedido

                    $("#btnEtapaResumo").attr('href', URL);
                 }
              });
            }

        },
```

O método está enviando todo o conteudo certinho em forma de mensagem para o whatsapp, ocorre que eu gostaria de mandar esse conteudo direto para impressora que fica na cozinha.
Alguem sabe me dizer como eu posso fazer isso ?

Ja tentei com da seguinte forma: criando uma nova janela e jogando o conteudo da variavel texo dentro da janela,

```
                  const win = window.open(' ', ' ', 'heigtht=600, width=600');
                  win.document.write(texto);
```

Acontece que dessa forma ai chega tudo sem formatação na janela e eu precisaria tambem de um botão nesta janela para imprimir e depois enviar para uma mini impressora termica.
Penso que a forma mais adequada seria enviar o pedido gerado diretamente para a impressora, sem a necessidade de criar essa tela.
Mas como fazer isso ?

Answer (score -5):

Um melhor formato seria gerar PDFs formatados para impressão. Contudo, a execução via JavaScript no navegador pode ser limitada, necessitando de soluções server-side ou integrações com o sistema operacional para efetivar a comunicação com a impressora térmica.

Voltando ao código, para imprimir pedidos na cozinha, crie um documento HTML formatado para impressão. Ajuste seu método para abrir uma nova aba e exibir esse conteúdo, permitindo a impressão automática. Isso simplifica o processo, mantendo a formatação adequada e facilitando a leitura na impressora térmica.

```
finalizarPedido: () => {
    if (meu_Carrinho.length > 0 && meu_Endereco != null) {
        let texto = 'Olá, eu gostaria de fazer um pedido,<br>';
        let itens = 'Itens do Pedido:<br><br>';

        $.each(meu_Carrinho, (i, e) => {
            itens += `*${e.quantidade}x* ${e.name}........R$ ${e.price.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',')} <br>`;
        });

        let enderecoCompleto = `<br>Endereço de Entrega:<br>${meu_Endereco.endereco}, ${meu_Endereco.numero}, ${meu_Endereco.bairro}<br>${meu_Endereco.cidade} - ${meu_Endereco.Uf} / ${meu_Endereco.cep} ${meu_Endereco.complemento}<br>`;
        let total = `<br>Total (com entrega): R$ ${(valor_Carrinho + valor_Entrega).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',')}<br>`;

        texto += itens + enderecoCompleto + total;

        const win = window.open('', '', 'width=800,height=600');
        win.document.write('<html><head><title>Pedido</title>');
        win.document.write('</head><body >');
        win.document.write(texto);
        win.document.write('</body></html>');
        win.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        win.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

        // Adiciona um pequeno atraso antes de disparar a impressão
        setTimeout(function () {
            win.print();
            win.close();
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Este método cria uma nova aba e utiliza window.print() para iniciar a impressão do conteúdo. Note que o design final será influenciado pelo CSS aplicado. Para assegurar que a impressão esteja alinhada com o formato da sua impressora térmica você tera que desenvolver.

PS.: Verifique a disponibilidade de SDKs ou APIs fornecidos pelo fabricante e considere o desenvolvimento de um aplicativo desktop usando Electron. Essas estratégias facilit uma integração direta e automatizada com a impressora, otimizando assim a eficiência e a confiabilidade do seu sistema de pedidos.

Comment: Comentários que fogem do núcleo da questão foram removidos. Sobre AIs generativas, estas não sabem programação ou concatenação de idéias, são apenas montadores de textos aparentemente coerentes, por isso postagens do tipo [não são aceitas neste site, que tem objetivo de ser um repositório confiável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8842/70) - uso pessoal é de cada um, mas aqui no site valem as regras oficiais decididas pela comunidade via voto - questões essas que podem ser tratadas nas respectivas postagens.